# SPDE via fixed point argument and Young's theorem

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(P_r)_{r\geq 0}$ be a strongly continuous semi-group (not necessarily the heat kernel).

It is well known that we can prove local well-posedness of a few SPDE using a fixed point argument: Young's theorem (see for example Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations by Bahouri et al., theorems 2.47-2.52, or Hairer introduction to Stochastic PDE lecture notes, theorem 7.7) which states that if $f\in\mathcal{C}^\alpha,h\in\mathcal{C}^\beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta>0,$ then $f\cdot h \in \mathcal{C}^{\min (\alpha,\beta)}.$

Let us consider the following mild solution formulation ($d$-dimensional):

$$u=P_ru_0+\int_0^rP_{r-q}(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u(q)|^2+\xi(q))dq,$$ where $\xi$ is a space-time white noise.

Suppose that all the above terms are well-defined (no ill-defined terms with positive regularities, even when considering products as defined in Young's theorem).

Can we prove using a fixed point argument that our problem might have a local solution, for example using a theorem similar to Hairer, theorem 7.7? **If so, how to deal with the gradient?**

Along the way we might need Schauder estimates which could be proven easily for a particular semi-group, the only concern is the gradient (of course it's possible to use regularity structures or paracontrolled distributions, but we prefer to use a fixed point argument first and/or Dabusche-DaPrato technique especially that everything is well-defined in term of regularity).